# Convert array in php to string format array

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array like this:

```
Array ( [0] => B121933, [1] => B105885, [1] => B105886 )
```

I need it in this format:

```
array('B121933','B105885','B105886')
```

I have used below code but it returns the same result:

```
foreach ($_finder_sku_array as $key => $value) {
    $arr[] = $value;
}

print_r($arr);

Array ( [0] => B121933 [1] => B105885 [2] => B105886 )
```

So please suggest an idea on how I can get a proper result.

Comment: This doesn't work! Keys must be unique

Comment: sorry i just forget to change it @Rizier123

Comment: array('B121933','B105885','B105886') === [0] => B121933 [1] => B105885 [1] => B105886

Comment: Yes but if i pass this to my magento function it was not work [0] => B121933 [1] => B105885 [1] => B105886  for me and this format it works for me array('B121933','B105885','B105886') @donald123

Comment: `array('B121933','B105885','B105886')` is equivalent to `Array ( [0] => B121933 [1] => B105885 [2] => B105886 )`

Comment: You realise that array elements are key/value pairs.... you can't have an array value without having an array key as well

Comment: What's your goal with this? They're the same. The problem is with how you're attempting to use the array.

Comment: `echo "array('", implode("','", $arr), "')";`

Comment: Can you post the function that uses this array?

Comment: Just use: `$_finder_sku_array` as parameter in your magneto function! Does that do the trick for you?

Comment: How about `var_export($array, true)`?

Answer (score 0):

And 
    `print_r(array('B121933','B105885','B105886'));` will show you : 
    Array ( [0] => B121933 [1] => B105885 [2] => B105886 );

Comment: Yes i know that but my magento function does not accept it in this format Array ( [0] => B121933 [1] => B105885 [2] => B105886 ); so i need it in the array('B121933','B105885','B105886')

Comment: what is the error/warning message that you have got from magneto ?

Answer (score 0):

try this :

> $array = array_values($array);

Comment: And exactly what will that achieve?

Comment: @MarkBaker Array ( [0] => B121933 [1] => B105885 [2] => B105886 )

Comment: So you've turned an enumerated array into the identical enumerated array

Answer (score 0):

This function converts the passed array in the string format you require.

```
<?php 

function arr_to_string($array){
  $new_array='array("';
  for($i=0;$i<sizeof($array)-1;$i++) {
    $new_array.=$array[$i].'","';
  }
  $new_array.=$array[sizeof($array)-1].'")';
  return $new_array;
}

 $array=array("B121933","B105885","B105886");
 echo arr_to_string($array);   // Outputs  array("B121933","B105885","B105886") 
?>
```

Comment: Your "function" can be simplified to `echo "array('", implode("','", $arr), "')";` as already shown in the comments

Comment: Though the result of the call to your function can't be echoed, as the function isn't returning anything